# Xpages: how to store a string as a resource bundle in files

Tags: properties, xpages, custom-controls

My menu is driven by a data structure, which I want to store as a file in the the Resources of my database. However, it appears that I cannot store (or don't know how to store) a multi-line string as a file resource.

My string will look like this:

```
[
 {
   "mnuNme": "by Author",
   "mnuTyp": "1",
   "mnuTrg": "xpNavigator3"
   },
   {
   "mnuNme": "by Location",
   "mnuTyp": "1",
   "mnuTrg": "xpView02"
  }
]
```

Is there any way to store this as a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a place to store and to maintain a menu as JSON data.

You can use a server side JavaScript library for this.
Assign your menu definition to a variable.
This way you have a syntax control included and you don't need to parse the JSON string as it is already a JavaScript array/object.

Example:

Server side JavaScript library "menu.jss":

```js
var menu = [
            {
               "mnuNme": "by Author",
               "mnuTyp": "1",
               "mnuTrg": "xpNavigator3"
            },
            {
               "mnuNme": "by Location",
               "mnuTyp": "1",
               "mnuTrg": "xpView02"
            }
           ];
```

XPage

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script
            src="/menu"
            clientSide="false">
        </xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:repeat
        id="repeat1"
        rows="0"
        var="entry"
        value="#{javascript:menu}">
        <xp:text
            escape="true"
            id="computedField1"
            value="#{entry.mnuNme}">
        </xp:text>
        <br />
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: A little note of caution on this - you are using a global variable - depending on your persistence settings / server performance / etc - at some point this global variable may become undefined due to garbage collection / and/or if the page gets written to disk for persistence. Global javascript server side variables should be considered a no-no. Only use SSJS includes for calling functions, etc. For example, you could create a function called menu() that returned the content of the string, then call menu() in your value (i.e. value="#{javascript:return menu();}" and it will be safer in scale.

Answer (score 1):

Why must it be multi-line? It appears you are trying to store JSON - minify it, and store as a single line. Keep an editable version somewhere else as your master, and re-minify when you want to deploy.

But, if you really want to do it, I believe the proper syntax is:

```
menuStructure=[ \
 { \
   "mnuNme": "by Author",\
   "mnuTyp": "1",\
   "mnuTrg": "xpNavigator3"\
   },\
   {\
   "mnuNme": "by Location",\
   "mnuTyp": "1",\
   "mnuTrg": "xpView02"\
  }\
]
```